# Ksoap2 header in/out

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

I was wondering if someone can help me with ksoap2 headers.
This is my soapUI request, which i need to convert for using a service with ksoap2.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tim="http://www.xxx.co.uk/schemas/111.Security">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tim:Login>
         <tim:userName>username</tim:userName>
         <tim:password>pass</tim:password>
      </tim:Login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is my class i eclipse:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://www.xxx.co.uk/schemas/111.Security/ISecurity/Login" ;
    private static final String METHOD_NAME="Login";
    private static final String NAMESPACE="http://www.xxx.co.uk/schemas/111.Security";
    private static final String URL="http://192.168.5.68:55969/Timesheet/yyy.111.Services/Security.svc";
```

and on buttonclicklistener are my actions:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {

        try 
        {            
            SoapObject soap = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            soap.addProperty("userName" ,txtUserName.getText().toString()); 
            soap.addProperty("password",txtPassword.getText().toString());

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            Element[] headers = new Element[1];             
            Element element = new Element();
            element.setName("ip");
            element.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);        
            element.addChild(Element.TEXT, "127.0.0.1");        

            headers[0] = element;                         
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);
            envelope.headerOut = headers;
            envelope.bodyOut = soap;


            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String resultValue = response.toString();

            lblStatus.setText(resultValue);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {                   
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Error").setMessage("Error").show();
        }

    }
```

where are my mistake?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: illegal argument exception

Comment: use Propertyinfo of that library and pass the argugements.

Comment: u mean username and password arguments?

Comment: yes arguments should be passed that way

Comment: like this? -
           
            PropertyInfo pip = new PropertyInfo();
            pip.setName("password");
            pip.setValue(txtPassword.getText().toString());
            pip.setType(int.class);
            request.addProperty(pip);

            PropertyInfo piu = new PropertyInfo();
            piu.setName("userName");
            piu.setValue(txtUserName.getText().toString());
            piu.setType(int.class);
            request.addProperty(piu);

Comment: did you try that way? whats the error?

Comment: Yes, error is illegal argument exception

Comment: i have one more question - pip.setType(int.class);  - what this means?

Comment: it is to pass what type of argument ! ( like string if you are passing a string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```